# custom settings in CKEditor config.js file

Tags: ckeditor

What are the custom settings i can do in CKEditor config.js file,
I changed a few, `config.font_defaultLabel = 'Arial';`
what are the other settings i can do in config.js file?
Please help me in this.

Answer (score 3):

Solution:
It took me quite a while to figure this out. 
Let us say you want to use Verdana as the default font. Here is what you can do:

1. Open contents.css and change the font tag:

   font-family: Verdana;
2. In the application/page where the output will be published, add this style:

   .entry-content {font-family: Tahoma;}

That's it! Now you have change the default font successfully. This works for the font size as well.

Answer (score 0):

They are available in the documentation: check [this](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html)

Comment: thanks for that, but i could not make BOLD or Italic as default. I need to make default font forecolor, font color and background color.Please help me in this.

Comment: Use a stylesheet to set the default look. If that's not enough, you'll have to create a custom plugin.